# Angular2 and Web Midi

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and I'm trying to use Angular2 to create a Web Midi app, but I'm having some troubles understanding certain errors. I believe I should be putting the Midi functions inside a Service, but do correct me if I'm wrong.

The example below works, when the midi variable and onMIDIMessage function is outside

```
var midi:any;

function onMIDIMessage(event) {
        console.log("msg received", event);
}

export class MidiService {

    onMidiInit() {
        if (navigator.requestMIDIAccess) {
            navigator.requestMIDIAccess({
                sysex: false
            }).then(this.onMIDISuccess, this.onMIDIFailure);
        } else {
            alert("No MIDI support in your browser.");
        }
    }

    onMIDISuccess(midiAccess) {
        console.log('MIDI Access Object', midiAccess);
        midi = midiAccess;
        console.log(midi);

        var inputs = midi.inputs.values();
        for (var input = inputs.next(); input && !input.done; input = inputs.next()) {
            input.value.onmidimessage = onMIDIMessage;
        }

    }

    onMIDIFailure(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

All is good and I can print out incoming MIDI messages with this. However, what I do not understand is that when the onMIDIMessage function and midi variable is inside the MidiService class, Chrome throws an error. Why is that happening?

> midi.service.ts:24 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property >'onMIDIMessage' of undefined at MidiService.onMIDISuccess (http://localhost:3000/app/midi.service.js:27:57)

```
var midi:any;

// Code that does not work
export class MidiService {

    onMidiInit() {
        if (navigator.requestMIDIAccess) {
            navigator.requestMIDIAccess({
                sysex: false
            }).then(this.onMIDISuccess, this.onMIDIFailure);
        } else {
            alert("No MIDI support in your browser.");
        }
    }

    onMIDISuccess(midiAccess) {
        console.log('MIDI Access Object', midiAccess);
        midi = midiAccess;
        console.log(midi);

        var inputs = midi.inputs.values();
        for (var input = inputs.next(); input && !input.done; input = inputs.next()) {
            input.value.onmidimessage = this.onMIDIMessage;
        }

    }

    onMIDIMessage(event) {
        console.log("msg received", event);
    }

    onMIDIFailure(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

---EDIT

The methods are called in the app.component.ts file.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MidiService} from './midi.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>',
    providers: [MidiService]
})
export class AppComponent { 
    constructor(midiService: MidiService) {
        midiService.onMidiInit();
    }
}
```

Comment: How and from where are these methods called?

Comment: When the MidiService class is initialized, onMIDIMessage is called each time there is an incoming MIDI message from a MIDI device that is connected to the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `this` doesn't point to the current class instance.

Add `.bind(this)` when you pass methods of the current class as callbacks:

```
input.value.onmidimessage = this.onMIDIMessage.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thanks! However, chrome is still throwing this error in the console:

Comment: midi.service.ts:23 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMIDIMessage' of undefined

Comment: Did you add it to `}).then(this.onMIDISuccess, this.onMIDIFailure);` like `}).then(this.onMIDISuccess.bind(this), this.onMIDIFailure.bind(this));`?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Any idea whats the issue for the midi:any variable as well? Putting it in the MidiService class will also throw the same error.

Comment: You need to use `this.midi` to access the variable when it is inside the class.